# Id Collision in the Sqlite Database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, unique-id

id in the Sqlite is not generating unique id when inserted in the sqlite database.
There are college list,university list and school list for which i have to bookmark.When i bookmark the 1st items of the school the the ist item of college and university are bookmarked.How can this be resolved??

DatabaseHelper class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DatabaseUpdatedListener databaseUpdatedListener;
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BookmarkDatabase";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK = "bookmark";
    //    Contact table columns name
    private static final String ID = "Id";
    private static final String NAME = "Name";
    private static final String ADDRESS = "Address";
    private static final String LOGO = "Logo";
    private static final String COUNTRY = "country";
    private static final String PHONE = "phone";
    private static final String EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String WEBSITE = "website";
    private static final String INSTITUTION_TYPE = "institution_type";
    private static final String ESTABLISHED_DATE = "establishment_date";
    private static final String ADMISSION_OPEN_FROM = "admission_open_from";
    private static final String ADMISSION_OPEN_TO = "admission_open_to";
    private static final String LATITUDE = "latitude";
    private static final String LONGITUDE = "longitude";

    String createTableBookmark = "Create table if not exists `Bookmark` (" + "`name`    TEXT," + "`location`    TEXT," + "`logo`    TEXT);";
    String CREATE_SCHOOL_BOOKMARK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK + "("
            + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT "
            + NAME + " TEXT, "
            + LOGO + " TEXT, "
            + ADDRESS + " TEXT, "
            + COUNTRY + " TEXT, "
            + PHONE + " TEXT, "
            + EMAIL + " TEXT, "
            + WEBSITE + " TEXT, "
            + INSTITUTION_TYPE + " TEXT, "
            + ESTABLISHED_DATE + " TEXT, "
            + ADMISSION_OPEN_FROM + " TEXT, "
            + ADMISSION_OPEN_TO + " TEXT, "
            + LATITUDE + " TEXT, "
            + LONGITUDE + " TEXT " + ")";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void insertBookmarkData(Bookmarkitem bookmarkitem) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put("name", bookmarkitem.name);
        content.put("location", bookmarkitem.address);
        content.put("logo", bookmarkitem.logo);

        db.insert("Bookmark", null, content);
    }

    public ArrayList<Bookmarkitem> getBookmarkist() {
        String sql = "select * from Bookmark ";
        ArrayList<Bookmarkitem> bookmarklist = new ArrayList<Bookmarkitem>();

        Cursor c = getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Bookmarkitem info = new Bookmarkitem();
            info.name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            info.address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("location"));
            info.logo = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("logo"));
            bookmarklist.add(info);
        }
        c.close();
        return bookmarklist;
    }

    public Bookmarkitem getBookmarkData(String bookmarkName) {
        String sql = "select * from Bookmark  where id='" + bookmarkName + "'";

        Cursor c = getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Bookmarkitem info = new Bookmarkitem();
            info.name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            info.address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("location"));
            info.logo = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("logo"));
        }
        c.close();
        Bookmarkitem info = null;
        return info;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_SCHOOL_BOOKMARK_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public void addSchoolBookmark(Bookmarkitem bookmarkitem, MenuItem menuItem) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ID, bookmarkitem.getBookmarkID());


        values.put(NAME, bookmarkitem.getName());
        values.put(LOGO, bookmarkitem.getLogo());
        values.put(ADDRESS, bookmarkitem.getAddress());

        values.put(COUNTRY, bookmarkitem.getCountry());
        values.put(PHONE, bookmarkitem.getPhone());
        values.put(EMAIL, bookmarkitem.getEmail());
        values.put(WEBSITE, bookmarkitem.getWebsite());
        values.put(INSTITUTION_TYPE, bookmarkitem.getInstitution_type());
        values.put(ESTABLISHED_DATE, bookmarkitem.getEstablishment_date());
        values.put(ADMISSION_OPEN_FROM, bookmarkitem.getAdmission_open_from());
        values.put(ADMISSION_OPEN_TO, bookmarkitem.getAdmission_open_to());
        values.put(LATITUDE, bookmarkitem.getLatitude());
        values.put(LONGITUDE, bookmarkitem.getLongitude());


        //inserting row
        if (db.insert(TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK, null, values) != -1) {
            //
            databaseUpdatedListener.setDatabaseSuccess(bookmarkitem.getName(), menuItem);


        }

     /*   else {
            databaseUpdatedListener.setDatabaseError("Failed to Delete");
        }   */

//        db.beginTransaction();


        db.close();
    }

    public List<Bookmarkitem> getAllSchoolBookmark() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK;
        List<Bookmarkitem> bookmarkitems = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Bookmarkitem bookmarkitem = new Bookmarkitem();
                bookmarkitem.setBookmarkID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                bookmarkitem.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                bookmarkitem.setLogo(cursor.getString(2));
                bookmarkitem.setAddress(cursor.getString(3));

                bookmarkitem.setCountry(cursor.getString(4));
                bookmarkitem.setPhone(cursor.getString(5));
                bookmarkitem.setEmail(cursor.getString(6));
                bookmarkitem.setWebsite(cursor.getString(7));
                bookmarkitem.setInstitution_type(cursor.getString(8));
                bookmarkitem.setEstablishment_date(cursor.getString(9));
                bookmarkitem.setAdmission_open_from(cursor.getString(10));
                bookmarkitem.setAdmission_open_to(cursor.getString(11));
                bookmarkitem.setLatitude(cursor.getString(12));
                bookmarkitem.setLongitude(cursor.getString(13));

                bookmarkitems.add(bookmarkitem);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return bookmarkitems;
    }

    public boolean removeBookmarkItem(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK, ID + "=" + id, null) > 0;
    }

    public Bookmarkitem getBoomarkDetailByID(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        String empName = "";
        try {
            Bookmarkitem bookmarkitem = new Bookmarkitem();
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK + " WHERE " + ID + "=?", new String[]{id + ""});
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

                cursor.moveToFirst();
                bookmarkitem.setBookmarkID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                bookmarkitem.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                bookmarkitem.setLogo(cursor.getString(2));
                bookmarkitem.setAddress(cursor.getString(3));

                bookmarkitem.setCountry(cursor.getString(4));
                bookmarkitem.setPhone(cursor.getString(5));
                bookmarkitem.setEmail(cursor.getString(6));
                bookmarkitem.setWebsite(cursor.getString(7));
                bookmarkitem.setInstitution_type(cursor.getString(8));
                bookmarkitem.setEstablishment_date(cursor.getString(9));
                bookmarkitem.setAdmission_open_from(cursor.getString(10));
                bookmarkitem.setAdmission_open_to(cursor.getString(11));
                bookmarkitem.setLatitude(cursor.getString(12));
                bookmarkitem.setLongitude(cursor.getString(13));
            }

            return bookmarkitem;
        } finally {

            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

BookmarkAdapter class

```
public class BookmarkAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Bookmarkitem> ourBookmarkList;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public BookmarkAdapter(Activity activity, List<Bookmarkitem> ourBookmarkList) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.ourBookmarkList = ourBookmarkList;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ourBookmarkList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return ourBookmarkList.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookmark_list, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView bookmarkLogo = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.bookmarklogo);
        TextView bookmarkTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookmarkTitle);
        TextView bookmarkAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookmarkAddress);
        Bookmarkitem m = ourBookmarkList.get(position);

        bookmarkLogo.setImageUrl(m.getLogo(), imageLoader);

        bookmarkTitle.setText("Name: " + m.getName());

        bookmarkAddress.setText("Address: " + String.valueOf(m.getAddress()));


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

DatabaseupdatedListener

```
  public interface DatabaseUpdatedListener {
        void setDatabaseSuccess(String schoolName, MenuItem item);
        void setDatabaseError(String failureMessage);
    }
```

there is no unique id generated when it is inserted in database.How can this be solved??

Comment: `id in the Sqlite is not generating unique id when inserted in the sqlite database` which values are generating ? and it is `Id` instead of `id` in your code, so use same everywhere

Comment: nothing happeneing

Comment: You are using `id` when querying data from table. use `Id` instead

Comment: can you please show where i have to change

Comment: In `getBookmarkData` method

Comment: i have changed ,nothing happens

Comment: @seon uninstall old app and run again

Comment: Hint: You miss a **comma** at the end of this line `+ ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT "`

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

**Different Field Name** .

```
 private static final String ID = "Id";
 String sql = "select * from Bookmark  where id='" + bookmarkName + "'"; // why id ? must be ID
```

- Rectify **getBookmarkData** Method

**DEMO EXAMPLE** .

```
      private static final String USER_ID= "user_id";

      String sql = "select * from Bookmark  where user_id='" + bookmarkName + "'";

     cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK + " WHERE " + USER_ID+ "=?", new String[]{id + ""});
```

Then **Uninstall old App** and run again .

Comment: can you please elaborate more

Comment: @seon okay . You are calling different name .

Comment: @seon did you understand what i am saying ?

Comment: new column with user_id is created which is made Autoincremented

Comment: @seon no problem for that

Comment: what is the advantage of Doing this??

Comment: @seon another problem will arise `select * from Bookmark  where user_id='" + bookmarkName` . I guess conflict will occur autoincrement `user_id` with `bookmarkName`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134944/discussion-between-seon-and-intellij-amiya).

Comment: It is generating uniquely, but i have made some coding mistake

Comment: @seon yes yes .was my answer helpful ?

Comment: I have not created another column ,as you said.

Comment: @seon did you rename your field ?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add `ID` column explicitly. Try as below.

Create a contract class for column names first

```
public static class ColumnNameEntry implements BaseColumns {
private static final String NAME = "Name";
private static final String ADDRESS = "Address";
private static final String LOGO = "Logo";
private static final String COUNTRY = "country";
private static final String PHONE = "phone";
private static final String EMAIL = "email";
private static final String WEBSITE = "website";
private static final String INSTITUTION_TYPE = "institution_type";
private static final String ESTABLISHED_DATE = "establishment_date";
private static final String ADMISSION_OPEN_FROM = "admission_open_from";
private static final String ADMISSION_OPEN_TO = "admission_open_to";
private static final String LATITUDE = "latitude";
private static final String LONGITUDE = "longitude";
}
```

Implementing `BaseColumns` class will give column `_id` automatically, which will be auto incremented

Now create table as below

```
String CREATE_SCHOOL_BOOKMARK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK + "("
        + ColumnNameEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY "....
```

Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) tutorial

Comment: can you please provide any link  which helps.

Comment: added reference in answer

Comment: After changing the database schema, you have to clear data of the app and reinstall it